# GMAIL API removes my html attributes when sending

Tags: gmail

**THE SITUATION:**

*What is this question all about and what am I doing?*

I am sending electronic mails *(e-mails)* with **PHP** GMAIL-API.

**How is it that I am sending e-mails?**

```
$contenido="Whatever <span style="color:green;">and</span> then img <img src='#' ... >";    

$strRawMessage = "From: Flauta <tallergranadosortiz@gmail.com>\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "To: <".$paquien.">\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($sujeto) . "?=\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= $contenido."\r\n";


// The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);

//The special value **me** can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
$objSentMsg = $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);

echo 'Awesome.... stuff was sent.';
```

**Are the e-mails actually being sent?**

Yes.

**But** this flowy stuff removing the image... and I do not know why.

**What am I receiving?**

In the mail i receive i just get plain tags without attributes.

**In this case**: `Whatever <span>and</span> then img <img>`

Do you know if I need to encode the content in any other special way or something?

It is my fault because I am doing it wrong.

But it is not my fault not to know what I am doing wrong.

So there is no fault at all.

Who was talking about fault anyways?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
```

instead of

```
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: You're a life saver, thanks a lot! Do you know any use case one may need to use "quoted-printable" ?

Comment: This did the trick for me!